# How to retrieve notification message intent.getExtras() when app is background FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using FCM for Simple notification

When the app is in foreground, everything working properly. I am getting a notification plus the data message inside the `onMessageReceived` method.

But when app is in background, I am getting notification in system tray. And when I click on the control, it goes to the main activity. And When I parse `intent.getExtras();`, I am getting only this key data - `google.sent_time`, `from`, `google.message_id`, `collapse_key`.

How to get the notification message title and Message which is visible in system tray from `intent.getExtras()`?

I am using FCM console for sending notification I don't have my dedicated server to do this.

Code for receiving the message:

```
final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
final Set<String> keySet = extras.keySet(); 
final Iterator<String> iterator = keySet.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) {     
    final String key = iterator.next(); 
    final Object o = extras.get(key); 
    System.out.println(key + ":" + o); 
}
```

Comment: Do include the code you have so far.

Comment: First of all be sure that you are receiving notifiaction message or payload message or Combination of both. Google has provided sample application please follow that or else please paste your code here.

Comment: Dude thanks for your advice. I already mentioned in question that I am getting both notification and data message when app is in the foreground. And When is in background when notification came in system tray - when clicked on it.  from intent.getExtras(); I am getting only mentioned keys. How to retrieve notification payload

Comment: post your onReceive() method's code!

Comment: " final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        final Set<String> keySet = extras.keySet();

        final Iterator<String> iterator = keySet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final String key = iterator.next();
            final Object o = extras.get(key);

            System.out.println(key + ":" + o);
        } "

Comment: this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/44150822/6632278 hope helps. Good luck

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As seen in the [Handling Messages for Android FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages), if the payload you sent has both notification and data, it will be handled separately. The notification part will be handled by the Notification Tray, while the data part will be in the extras of the intent.

AFAIK, there is no way to get the notification payload when the app is in background (always handled by the Notification Tray). However, what you could do is add custom key-value pairs to your data payload instead, like so:

```
{
"data": {
      "notification_title": "title here",
      "notification_message": "message here"
     }
}
```

Of course you'll have to make sure that the data value for `notification_title` and `notification_message` is the same as to what you set it in the notification payload. Then just retrieve it from the Intent extras like usual.

Comment: I am using firebase console for sending notification. When I click on notification.  I am getting only google.sent_time, from, google.message_id, collapse_key. this keys. I want message and title key

Comment: Sorry. What you're saying is a bit confusing. As I understand, you want to retrieve the `title` and `message` from the message you sent using the Firebase Console when your app is in background. Seeing as you sent the message from the console, it will be treated as a `notification` payload. What you have to do is add in a **custom** key-value pair (as I mentioned in my answer) in the ***Advanced Option*** section, then parse it in the Intent extras with the key you used.

Comment: Currently I am doing same. But is there any other way. Because I have to add title and message twice. In firebase console.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to retrieve the notification payload values when the is in background. It will always be handled by the Notification Tray.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I have to set my own server and send only data payload so even if my app is in background onMessageReceived get called. In this case generation of notification we have to take care. Correct

Answer (score 7):

Firebase Notfication will behave as Data Message when your app is in background or is killed. In these Scenarios, if you want to retrieve your notification Message then you must define it in Key Value pair under

**Advanced Option of FCM Console**

[image]

and then retrieve this message by using this **key** in your activity which will be open by tabbing the Notification.

```
 if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Object value ;
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            if(key.equals("Message Key")) {
                 value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key); // value will represend your message body... Enjoy It
                 Log.d("NotificationTag" , key+"____" + value);
                }
          }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override the handleIntent() method of FirebaseMessagingService .class it will called in both foreground and background mode and here your can get and parse notification key and payload data

```
public void handleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
    String title = bundle.getString("gcm.notification.title");
     String body = bundle.getString("gcm.notification.body");
    }
```

Note: it will worked for play service 11

Comment: FirebaseMessagingService does not have a method called handleIntent. See doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService. This comment needs to be reviewed