# How to get the notification title and body using cordova-plugin-fcm on an ionic 1 app

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to send push notifications to my application using postman for testing.

I am using the following code to send the push.

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Title",
    "body":"this is a notification to a specific topic",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",  
  },
  "data":{
    "action":"ping"
  },
  "to":"/topics/Topic_1",
  "priority":"high"
}
```

and I am using this code to handle the notification on my app:

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.wasTapped){
      //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user. 
      alert('notification tapped'+ JSON.stringify(data) );
    }else{
      //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified. 
      alert('application is open'+ JSON.stringify(data) );
    }
});
```

it is all working except i cannot get the title and the body to use them in my application, all I am getting is the following:

> Object {wasTapped: false, action: "ping"}

I cannot find a way to get the notification title and body.

I know I can copy them to the data section but that's not logical *its a dirty workaround*

so any idea how to get the notification data?
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Basing from the behavior shown, I'm presuming that the client platform is Android. If so, then this is working as expected.

When sending a combination of both `notification` and `data` in your message payload, the Android System tray will be the one to handle the values in `notification`. The *dirty workaround* you mentioned is the only workaround so far -- a workaround that I actually suggested on [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41458543/4625829) as well.

Comment: thank you for the information.
this behavior is the same for IOS?

Comment: [iOS handles messages differently](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive)